# How do I make a "Star this project on GitHub" link?

Tags: github

On a couple blog posts, talking about software projects I've seen a small thing that when clicked causes you to star the project on GitHub. It's about the same size as one of the things to like something on Facebook. I want one of those for [this](https://github.com/jsnider3/GitHubBOC) project. How do I make one of those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like GitHub does provide this functionality - See https://buttons.github.io/

Comment: Yeah, this was a new feature from a few years after I asked this.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like this is provided by GitHub per se, but the source code for the buttons I saw is available at https://ghbtns.com/.